# Is There Any Method To Put Any Series Into Sigma Notation

Tags: summation, taylor-expansion

I was working on a MacLaurin Series expansion and this is the sum that i came up with: $$\frac{1}{1!}x+\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}+\frac{9}{5!}x^{5}+\frac{225}{7!}x^{7}+\frac{11025}{9!}x^{9}+...$$

I was wondering if there was a simple way to put this into sigma notation just using simple operations like factorials and exponentiation. This would be nice I also want to know if there is a general method for this.

**Thanks!**

Comment: What pattern do your numerators follow?  This is unclear.  What should be the next numerator and how did you know from what is pictured so far?

Comment: You can look it up in a database, but other than that we don't have the crystal ball.

Comment: Yes Sine of the Time I accidentally misspelled it.

Comment: Ok Thanks Giulio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have a known series expansion. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1!}x}&\color{blue}{+\frac{1}{3!}x^{3}+\frac{9}{5!}x^{5}+\frac{225}{7!}x^{7}+\frac{11025}{9!}x^{9}+\cdots}\\
&=x+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{((2n-1)!!)^2}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}\right)^2\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n)!}{\left(2^nn!\right)^2}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}\tag{3}\\
&=\int_{0}^x\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}t^{2n}\,dt\\
&=\int_{0}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\arcsin(x)}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!$.
- In (2) we use $(2n)!!=2^nn!$.
- In (3) we use a representation with *[central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)* and the well-known series expansion
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\tag{4}
  \end{align*}
  at $x=0$. We observe that (3) is the integral of (4) with $x$ replaced by $\frac{x^2}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to convert the series in hypergeometric form and lookup the corresponding elementary functional form from a database.

Rewrite your series by extracting one $x$ so that initial term has no $x$ term.

$$ S = x \left\{ 1+\frac{1}{3!}x^2+\frac{3 \cdot 3}{5!}x^4+\cdots + \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n} + \cdots \right\}
$$

calculating the ratio of successive terms
$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n} = \frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n+3)(2n+2)} x^2$$

and converting $n$ terms with coefficients $1$.

$$
\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n} = \frac{\left(n+\frac 1 2\right)^2}{\left(n + \frac 3 2\right)(n+1)} x^2
$$

From this rational form we can construct the series form back, now in [Pochhammer notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), ready to be converted to hypergeometric form

$$ S = x \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac {\left( \frac 1 2 \right)_n^2} 
                                 {\left( \frac 3 2 \right)_nn!}x^{2n} 
    $$

finally in Hypergeometric notation,
$$
S = x \cdot {}_{2}F_{1} (\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2; \frac 3 2; x^2)
$$

The next step is looking for the elementary function representation from a table (similar to integral tables). For example [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4), equation 15.4.4

From the reference you can conclude that

$$ S = \arcsin(x) $$

Note that this approach requires minimal or no insight, just standard transformation of series terms ratio to Pochhammer notation, which can be easily automated.

Comment: Note that with the Σ notation, $n$ starts at 0 and goes to ∞.

Comment: @Alex Beam please see my updated answer.